# Windows Store C#: System.UnauthorizedAccessException writing image file

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store

I'm currently creating a Windows store app (C#) that pulls an image from a URL at a regular interval (every 3 seconds) and displays it on a page. The image is successfully downloaded to temporary app storage once, but I get an Access denied (UnauthorizedAccessException) the second time round.

This is most likely because my app is using the file as a source for a bitmap (so it's still open) when it tries to overwrite it with a new image.

Is there a workaround for this that avoids the concurrency problem?

```
public async void GetLocalImageAsync(string internetUri, string uniqueName)
   {
       //Set up the web request and pass credentials.
       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(internetUri);
      request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("james", "jam3s");
        //get response
          using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
          {
              using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
              {
                  var desiredName = string.Format(uniqueName);
                  //create the file.
                  var file = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync(desiredName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                  using (var filestream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                  {
                      await stream.CopyToAsync(filestream);

                      //update the bitmap image with the file we just downloaded.
                      BitmapImage c1src = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appdata:///temp/camera1imgsrc.png"));
                      camera1img.Source = c1src;

                  }
              }
          }


   }
```

Comment: What I'd do is I will create a temporary copy of the image that you are manipulating and then once I am done with whatever I want to do with the temp image, I will then overwrite the original image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store each downloaded file with a different name (e.g. by adding a timestamp or sequential number to the root file name). After you download it, you can set the source to this new downloaded file and delete the previous one after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle file with ReaderWriterLockSlim class.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx